# Call nested function with if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am try to call a nesting function like below:

```js
function public(val) {
  if (val == "exist") {
    function runList() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i]();
      }
    }
  }
  public.runList = runList;
}

var publicExist = "exist";

function test() {
  console.log(test)
}

function testE() {
  console.log(testE)
}

public(publicExist);

public.runList(test, testE);
```

I want to fire function, but these codes only show the text, how can I do?

Comment: What is fire nesting?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around `'test'` and `'testE'`, which I am assuming you wanted to log to the console as strings.

```js
function public(val) {
  if (val == "exist") {
    function runList() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i]();
      }
    }
  }
  public.runList = runList;
}

var publicExist = "exist";

function test() {
  console.log('test')
}

function testE() {
  console.log('testE')
}

public(publicExist);

public.runList(test, testE);
```

Comment: I think I closed it already can you please check? 
if not could you please tell me where to go to close it.
thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes in test and testE method's console -

```js
function public(val) {
 if (val == "exist") {
    function runList() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        
             arguments[i]();
        }
    }
  }
  public.runList = runList;
}

var publicExist = "exist";

function test(){
  console.log('test')
}

function testE(){
  console.log('testE')
}

public(publicExist);

public.runList(test,testE);
```